# testing "this" in angular with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine

I want make a test code using jasmine, the code like here:

```
  toggle(id) {
    this.selected = id;
    this.show2 = !this.show2;
  }
```

this is my test function:

```
  test('test toogle function', () => {
    const spy = spyOn(component, 'toggle')
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
```

when I try make a test but just toggle(id) 
has been test and pass in coverage 
and function in toggle(id) not tested, how to test the function in toggle(id)?

thanks

Comment: Can you please tell what exactly do you mean bytesting this and show your test case

Comment: I already update my code

Comment: Can you share the controller or service where toggle is written along with entire test file

Comment: You are spying and stubbing the very function you want to test - this is unlikely what you meant to do. Instead you should call component.toggle(someTestId) and check the values of component.selected and component.show2 to verify they were set properly.

Comment: `spyOn(component, 'toggle').and.callThrough();` will do the trick, right?

Comment: @CastroRoy - I doubt it.  That will allow the function to execute, sure, but what is the point of the spy?  You want to spy on the functions that are being called FROM the functions under test, in order to be sure they were called properly, not the functions under test themselves - those should be called directly and fully because that is what is being tested.